# vuejs both components get prop from App.js, but one component lost prop data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

When I refresh my browser few times when I am on "ActorDetails.vue" page/component, not often but sometimes, I lost my `actorsData` prop data(should have array of 5 objects but become empty array), at first, I thought it's an API's problem but when I try to `console.log()` the data inside of "App.js", the data exist... I can't seem to find where the problem is.(Also I did try refresh the browser few times when I am on "ActorsList.vue" page/component, the prop data always exist)

Both pages/components("ActorList.vue" and "ActorDetails.vue") gets `topActors` data from "App.vue".

(Comments in code)

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view name="homePage" />
    <router-view :actorsData="topActors" /> <== "ActorList.vue" and "ActorDetails.vue" use this "router-view"
    <div class="over-limit-resolution">Over 4k</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getActors } from "./util/TheMoveDatabase";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      topActors: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    getActors.then((result) => {
      console.log(result); <== Data always came back from API even when my "actorsData" prop inside of "ActorsDetails.vue" lost it's data.
      this.topActors = result;
    });
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

**ActorsList.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="actors-list">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>

    <div class="actors-list-container" v-if="allFiveActors">
      <div
        class="actor-container"
        v-for="actorData in actorsData"
        :key="actorData.id"
      >
        <router-link :to="'/actorslist/' + actorData.id">
          <h3>{{ actorData.name }} | {{ actorData.id }}</h3>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ActorsList",
  props: ["actorsData"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    allFiveActors() {
      return this.actorsData.length > 0;
    },
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.actorsData); <== Also tried to refresh the browser when I am on this page/component, prop data always exist.
  },
};
```

**ActorsDetails.vue** (Page/Component that lost prop data)

```
<template>
  <div class="actor-details">
    <router-link to="/actorslist">Actors List</router-link>
    <h1>Details page</h1>
    <div class="actor-details-container" v-if="actorDetails">
      <div class="actor-detail-info">
        <h3>{{ actorDetails.name }}</h3>
        <p>Birthday: {{ actorDetails.birthday }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getActorDetails } from "../util/TheMoveDatabase";
export default {
  name: "ActorDetails",
  props: ["actorsData", "actorId"],
  data() {
    return {
      actorDetails: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkCurrentActorExist() {
      const currentActor = this.getCurrentActor;
      // console.log(currentActor);
      if (!currentActor) {
        // this.$router.push("/");
        console.log("does not exist");
      }
    },

    getActor() {
      const currentActor = this.getCurrentActor;
      console.log(currentActor);
      console.log("RAN");

      if (currentActor) {
        getActorDetails(this.actorId).then((result) => {
          this.actorDetails = result;
          console.log(this.actorDetails);
        });
      }
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.checkCurrentActorExist();
    this.getActor();
    console.log(this.actorsData); <== When I am on this page/component and refresh the browser few times, sometimes my "actorsData" prop data is lost.
    console.log(this.actorId);
  },

  computed: {
    getCurrentActor() {
      return this.actorsData.find(
        (actor) => actor.id === parseInt(this.actorId)
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Routes.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        components: {
            homePage: Home,
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/actorslist',
        name: 'ActorsList',
        component: () => import('../views/ActorsList.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/actorslist/:actorId',
        name: 'ActorDetails',
        component: () => import('../views/ActorDetails.vue'),
        props(route) {
            // console.log(route);
            return {
                actorId: route.params.actorId,
            };
        },
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Please define "lost".

Comment: should have 5 objects in the array but become empty array.(updated in question)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but maybe your loading-method sometimes takes to much time and the empty array already has been passed to the component.
I would try to clear the array and re-fill it with the loaded data instead of creating a new array (I would try to empty it using `splice` or `pop` and then refill it with `push`)